# A word for taking the commonly-held meaning of a word rather than its literal meaning?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for (mis)taking a word or phrase for its common meaning rather than it's correct/literal meaning.

e.g. My wife told me my mother's meal was delicious. I later told mother about my wife's "criticism" of her meal, because although it's not commonly used as such, "criticism" can be positive as well as negative.

Now my mother is offended (having assumed the negative implication) because she took the word "criticism" [too] ________ .
 ?

It's not "literally" because of course she didn't take it literally, and I don't think it's "figuratively" because well "criticism" isn't a figure of speech...

**EDIT**

This is not a question about the word "criticism" - I was just using that as an example! FYI the conversation above never took place!

There are some words which are commonly misunderstood, and because of that, miscommunication occurs. The word I'm looking for is what the listener is doing when they misunderstand it for that reason.

Comment: As per [Clare's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/417285/91730) your example doesn't actually show what you want it to. If you can find a more clear-cut example, I think this would be a great question.

Comment: The question needs rewriting. Both 'correct' and 'literal' are used erroneously here (and I assume the self-referential nature is unintended). The most common meaning, as confirmed by being listed first in most if not all respected non-historic English dictionaries, must be labelled 'correct' and almost always 'literal'.

Comment: In what way is the commonly-held meaning of a word not the literal meaning?

Comment: Can you give other examples of "words that are commonly misunderstood"?

Comment: "Criticism" is not a word that is commonly misunderstood. Your example is using a specialized meaning (a critique)  in a context (praising home cooking) in which the general meaning (finding fault) is the normal, everyday meaning. It's a terrible example.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t think there is a *single* word that captures this. In the context of your example, I might say:

> She took the word “criticism” too **specifically**.

That is, she took it for its most common specific meaning (a negative critique) instead of its general meaning (analysis & judgement of both pros and cons). In general, I might use a word or phrase that gives a judgement about the situation, not the word itself, such as:

> She took the word “criticism” too **negatively**.

In this case, the literal *denotation* of the word “criticism” was intended, but its *connotation* was what caused the trouble. So if you’re being a bit technical, you could say:

> She took the word “criticism” too **connotatively**.
>
> She took a negative connotation from the word “criticism”.

Answer (score 0):

The word for taking the commonly held meaning of a word, rather than taking it literally, is **comprehension**, or perhaps simply *normal*.  ***This is how language works***.  All language involves inference - the listener has to guess at what the speaker means, taking into account context and their knowledge of the speaker and what they might want to say.  It's fundamentally difficult and error prone.

Almost all words have multiple meanings.  If you wanted someone to infer a specific meaning, and they don't, then that's a communication failure: not necessarily anyone's fault, just a consequence of the messy ambiguous nature of language.

However, if the meaning that the speaker intended was **not** the commonly held meaning, and they didn't give the listener any other information to help them **infer** that fact, then the communication failure is **the fault of the speaker**.  The speaker is being overly literal, and the listener has done nothing wrong.

So, if the listener takes something too literally, then you could argue it's the fault of the listener.  If they assume you're using the commonly held meaning of a word, with no other information to indicate otherwise, then they're behaving normally, and the speaker (you, in this instance) is at fault.

The normal way to correct this would be to say "Sorry, I was being a bit too literal, I meant to say...".  If you insist that the listener is at fault then you're being foolish.

Comment: Under certain circumstances, one might say the listener is being *overly sensitive*, but that is not the case for the example provided in the question.